# Using 'continue' with modulo

Tags: c#, if-statement, continue

I'm kinda new at c# programming so take it easy on me.

I couldn't find the answer to my (most likely) simple an stupid question (there's no stupid questions!!) so I post here.

I need to write a program which shows numbers from 1 to 10 that aren't divisble by 2, 3 and 8 using "continue" instruction.

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0 && i % 8 == 0)  continue;
                Console.Write("{0} ", i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

It doesn't work, tho. The main issue is using &/&& operator. It should return both true and true. Help :(

Comment: "aren't divisble by 2, 3 and 8" .. maybe "aren't divisble by 2, 3 or 8" ?

Comment: @JacekCz nope, "aren't divisible  by 2, 3 AND 8". Why && is not working?

Comment: first number match this condition is 24

Comment: Do this and you will know why: `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", i % 2, i % 3, i % 8);`

Comment: yeah I made a mistake while rewriting the task content, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to write a program which shows numbers from 1 to 10 that aren't divisble by 2, 3 and 8 using "`continue`" instruction.

The minimum number that can be divided by 8 with no remainder is 8. So the only numbers that *could* qualify are 8, 9 or 10.

```
if (8 % 2 == 0 && 8 % 3 == 0 && 8 % 8 == 0) // false
if (9 % 2 == 0 && 9 % 3 == 0 && 9 % 8 == 0) // false
if (10 % 2 == 0 && 10 % 3 == 0 && 10 % 8 == 0) // false
```

None of the numbers 8, 9, 10 can be divided by 2, 3, and 8 with a remainder of 0, so of course *all* numbers would be printed out, as `continue` would never be triggered. Are you sure it's "2, 3, AND 8" and not "2, 3, OR 8"?

```
if ((i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) || (i % 8 == 0))  continue;
```

Comment: wait, you're right, I've made a mistake while rewriting content of the task lmao, thanks man cause otherwise I would be sitting all night at this!